# Parsing XML files with Java and spaces in file path

Tags: java, xml, spaces, filepath

I have files on my file system, on Windows XP. I want to parse them using Java (JRE 1.6).

Problem is, I don't understand how Java and Xerces work together when the file path has spaces in it.

If the file has no spaces in its path, all works fine.

If there are spaces, I may have this kind of trouble, *even if I call the parser with a FileInputStream instance* :

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: .
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
```

(`sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.openServer` ??? Wtf ?)

or else this kind of trouble :

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: d
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
```

(It says `unknown protocol: d` because, I guess, the file is on the D drive.)

Has anyone any clue of why that happens, and how to circumvent the problem ? I tried to supply my own EntityResolver but my log tells me it  is not even called before the crash.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the code calling the parser.

```
public Document fileToDom(File file) throws ProcessException {
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = db.newDocumentBuilder();
        if (this.errorHandler!=null){
            builder.setErrorHandler(this.errorHandler);}
        else {
            builder.setErrorHandler(new DefaultHandler());
        }
        FileInputStream test= new FileInputStream(file);
        doc = builder.parse(test);
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {...}
    ...
}
```

---

For the moment I find myself forced to remove the DOCTYPE before the parse, which removes all the problems, and the DTD validation... Not so great a solution.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to call the xml parser?  You should considering using a URI path.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just using `DocumentBuilder.parse(filename)`?

If so, that's failing because it expects a URI. Open a `FileInputStream` to the file, and then pass that to `DocumentBuilder.parse(InputStream)`.

Comment: I am using DocumentBuilder.parse(InputStream).

Answer (score 1):

Try this URI style:

> file:///d:/folder/folder%20with%20space/file.xml

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's trying to connect to a URL in the doctype header so it can download it in order to validate the document against the downloaded DTD.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(test));
doc = builder.parse(is);
```

instead of just parsing the 'test'